# Which is more efficient between texelfetch() and imageLoad() in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

If I just need to read data from BO,I have two methods.First is to load data to buffer textures and then read data by `texelfetch()` in shaders. Second,load data to buffer textures and bind buffer textures to image unit, then I can read data by `imageLoad()`.I want to know which is more efficient if there is great deal of data?

Comment: @Moonchild: "*If I just need to read data from BO,I have two methods.*" Or you can use an SSBO. If image load/store is available to you, so are SSBOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the specific case and the hardware being used. In general, imageLoad() will be more efficient than texelfetch() if there is a great deal of data. However, the performance difference between the two methods may be negligible in many cases. It's best to benchmark both methods on the hardware you are using to get an accurate comparison.

Answer (score -3):

Reading data from a buffer texture using texelfetch() in a shader is generally more efficient than binding the buffer texture to an image unit and using imageLoad() to read the data. This is because texelfetch() is designed specifically for reading texture data and can be optimized for this purpose, while imageLoad() is more general-purpose and may not be as efficient when used to read data from a buffer texture. The choice between texelfetch() and imageLoad() will depend on your specific use case and how you want to access the data in the buffer texture.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml

Comment: I know *what* `texelFetch` does. But there's nothing on that page that suggests the performance difference you claim.

Comment: The performance characteristics of different GPU architectures and driver implementations can vary, so the relative performance of texelfetch and imageLoad may not be the same in all cases, but since texelFetch is specifically designed for reading texture data, using it to read data from a buffer texture should be more efficient than using imageLoad(), (hence why imageLoad is more general-purpose)

Comment: But a buffer texture isn't *really* a texture; it's a buffer masquerading as a texture (mainly because there didn't used to be a way to access a buffer arbitrarily otherwise). Vulkan doesn't even consider its equivalent functionality to be a texture; its descriptor is not a "sampled image", but a "texel buffer" (though SPIR-V still uses a texture accessing function to access them). So do you have *evidence* besides speculation about how you think these features are meant to be used?

Comment: It is generally accepted in the graphics programming community that texelfetch is more efficient for reading data from buffer textures, especially on older hardware. Sorry if my previous comment gave the impression that this was simply my speculation.

Comment: What constitutes "older hardware"? I presume you're not talking about pre-GL 4 hardware.

Comment: When I referred to "older hardware," i wasnt  referring to any specific hardware generation or graphics API version. I was simply suggesting that texelfetch() may be more efficient on some hardware platforms compared to others.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something more concrete than a general "some hardware platforms". It'd also be good if you had links to where this "generally accepted" notion has some evidentiary support.